# The spacer_template option syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Why this line does not treat `spacer_template` as an option specifying a partial to be rendered between elements

```
render @picture.tags, spacer_template: "space_divider"
```

whilst this one does:

```
render partial: @picture.tags, spacer_template: "space_divider"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`render` needs you to specify `partial:` if you're adding more options than just the partial name. See the docs [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials) (Section 3.4.3)